# Resizing Elements For Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, resolution

I know this is probably a very common question, but being new to HTML, CSS, JS. I really wanted a direct answer, so I'm sorry if this is a duplicate.

I'm currently working on a wordle clone and I'm having trouble with the sizing for the mobile devices. On my computer, the sizing looks perfect. However, when I access it on my phone the keyboard at the bottom seems to be really small.

If I could get some assistance with fixing this issue that would be great! Thanks!

Here is my relevant HTML code:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale =1, user-scalable=no">
```

Here is all my relevant CSS code:

```
.keyboard-row {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.key-tile {
    /* Box */
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    width: 5%;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 1px;

    /* Text */
    font-size: auto;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

The mobile verson looks like this:
[image: Wordle clone on mobile]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **rem** unit instead of **pixels(px)** in your css while styling your keys and text as the rem and em helps to adjust relative to your parent container and helps to make the items reponsive.
or you can also make use of **media queries** to fix your problem.
Hope that this might help to fix your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've decided to use vh and vw but I want to be able to change the value that they are being multiplied by spontaneously. For example, sometimes I want it to be width: 45vh and other times I want it to be width: 55vh. Do you know how I could do this?